# Verizon iPhone 4 detection

Tags: platform, iphone-4

Using the platform detection when detecting original iPhone 4 gives me "iPhone3,1". Is the identifier for the Verizon (CDMA) iPhone 4 "iPhone3,2"? I can't test it, as I'm outside the US.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like it's iPhone3,3 according to [everyipod.com](http://www.everyipod.com/iphone-specs/apple-iphone-4-verizon-cdma-specs.html) and [geekbench.ca](http://browse.geekbench.ca/geekbench2/view/369525). There doesn't seem to be an official iPhone3,2.

Answer (score 0):

[Apple Insider](http://www.appleinsider.com/articles/11/01/31/apple_posts_ios_4_2_6_for_cdma_iphone_ahead_of_verizon_launch.html) reports that it's **iPhone3,3**. Do you need to know this for a specific reason?